# I am making an API call using axios in reactJS but getting extra results than expected ones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am learning `ReactJs` for my internship project and I am making an `API` call using `Axios` as in the code file SearchForm.js (pasted below). On every API call, I am getting the total pages available in the DB. I have tested a request in `Postman`.

**Example API request:**

```
https://api.mycareerdreams.com/api/get_jobs
```

**Form data:**

```
page=" " 
location="Karachi" 
keyword="software" 
skills=" "
```

In postman, I am getting 1 page but using `axios` I am getting whole `JSON` file. I know I am making some silly mistake but unable to figure it out.

**Source Code is:**

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SearchForm from './SearchForm';
// import DataDisplay from './DataDisplay';


class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            location_get: [],
            skills_get: []
        }

    };

    getDataForDropDowns = async () => {
        const response = await axios.post('https://api.mycareerdreams.com/api/get_jobs', {
            page: "1",
            location: "",
            keyword:"",
            skills:""
          });


        this.setState({location_get: response.data.dropdowns.location});
        this.setState({skills_get: response.data.dropdowns.skills});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getDataForDropDowns();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ui container" style={{marginTop: '10px'}}>
                <SearchForm location_data={this.state.location_get} skills_data={this.state.skills_get}/>
                <br/><hr />
                {/* <DataDisplay jobs_data={this.state.jobs_data_get} /> */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**SearchForm.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
// import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import LocationDropDowns from './LocationDropDowns';
// import DataDisplay from './DataDisplay';

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    // state = { rm: ''}
    state = {
        keyword_search:'',
        location_search: '',
        skills_search:'',
        jobs_data: [],
        total_pages:''
    }

    handleLocationChange = event => {
        this.setState({location_search: event.target.value});
    }

    handleKeywordChange = event => {
        this.setState({keyword_search: event.target.value});
    }

    getSearchData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.post('https://api.mycareerdreams.com/api/get_jobs', {
            page: " ",
            location: this.state.location,
            keyword:this.state.key_word,
            skills:" "
        });

        console.log("total pages", response.data.total_pages);

        console.log(response.data.jobs_data);
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({jobs_data: response.data.jobs_data});
        this.setState({total_pages: response.data.total_pages});
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        // alert('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.location);
        console.log(this.state.keyword_search);
        console.log(this.state.location_search);
        this.getSearchData();
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="ui segment">
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="ui form">
                        <div className="field">
                            <label>Search</label>
                            <input
                                name="keyword" 
                                type="text" 
                                value={this.state.keyword_search} 
                                onChange={this.handleKeywordChange} 
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Pick your Location:
                                <select name="location" onChange={this.handleLocationChange}>
                                    <option value=" ">Select Location</option>
                                    <LocationDropDowns locations_list={this.props.location_data} />                            
                                </select>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
export default SearchForm;
```

**LocationDropDowns.js**

```
import React from 'react';
class LocationDropDowns extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (this.props.locations_list.map((location) => {
            return (
                <option key={location} value={location}>{location}</option> 
            )})
        );
    }
};

export default LocationDropDowns;
```

**API Call Results:**

Getting the following results on calling this method which is written in SearchForm.js:

```
getSearchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post('https://api.mycareerdreams.com/api/get_jobs', {
        page: " ",
        location: this.state.location,
        keyword:this.state.key_word,
        skills:" "
    });

    console.log("total pages", response.data.total_pages);

    console.log(response.data.jobs_data);
    console.log(response.data);
    this.setState({jobs_data: response.data.jobs_data});
    this.setState({total_pages: response.data.total_pages});
}
```

**Console Output:**
[image]

Can someone point out the mistake that I am making so far? Thanks

**Edited part:**

From the network tab, I checked the request headers and its sending request's form data as request payload is it making the difference?
[image]

Comment: Axios will send data as json by default but I think (not sure) you are sending as form encoded data in Postman. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah body>form-data in the postman request

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. You have 2 calls to the API (why?). If you're talking about the call in `getSearchData` is your question why there are 20 items in the result while you expect to be less because you filtered by free text and location?

Comment: One call I am making on page load to get the data to populate the dropdown options and in second call i want to fetch the data for the parameters that i am giving from my stat variable

Comment: Several options in the linked duplicate above should help

Comment: API limit per page is 20. 
So in postman its showing "total_pages": 1
for the parameters that i have pasted above

Comment: The way you call axios is incorrect, you need to specify your query params option like this  ` data: { ... }`

Comment: Are you sure that `this.state.location` and `this.state.key_word` have the values you expect? Can you show the call payload looks like? You can post a screenshot of the call like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkMFh.png

Comment: @RicoChen it's true only if you call to just `axios()` but if you call `axios.post`, the second argument will be the payload just like OP did: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfnW4.png

Comment: @MoshFeu sir I have updated the question in the heading "Edited Part:"

Comment: Sorry @MoshFeu sir, I was making a silly mistake and that is I didn't mention the Form method as POST in the JSX

Comment: Secondly @charlietfl thanks for sharing the link. Thanks all.

Comment: What do you mean? You did use `axios.post`..

Comment: Yeah. I mean I wasn't giving the method="post" in the form. Otherwise its working. Thanks for the help